# how to validate password in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

could you please tell me how to validate password in angular js .Actually I have two password in my form .one is password and other is confirmed password .When both are same then it is valid else form is invalid .I apply validation for min length and max length.but how to compare password with confirmed password in angular js

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVpeeP

```
<div>
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="user.password" name="password" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="5" required style="width: 300px;padding: 20px;margin-top: 50px">
    <span ng-show="myform.password.$dirty &&myform.password.$error.required">Required</span>
    <span ng-show="myform.password.$dirty && myform.password.$error.minlength">too short</span>
    <span ng-show="myform.password.$dirty && myform.password.$error.maxlength">too Long</span>

</div>

<div>
    <input type="password" placeholder="confirmed password" ng-model="user.confiredpassword" name="confiredpassword" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="5" required style="width: 300px;padding: 20px;margin-top: 50px">
    <span ng-show="myform.confiredpassword.$dirty && myform.confiredpassword.$error.required">Required</span>
    <span ng-show="myform.confiredpassword.$dirty && myform.confiredpassword.$error.minlength">too short</span>
    <span ng-show="myform.confiredpassword.$dirty && myform.confiredpassword.$error.maxlength">too Long</span>

</div>
```

if both password are not same .then I need to display error ?
Thanks

Comment: Check this link http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/10/13/confirm-password-validation-in-angularjs.aspx

Comment: Wow ... never search on google for this. NEVER !!!!

Comment: there are two pages of different results, with code examples, on any web search of this topic.  At least perform *a little* research before coming here and posting a question asking for someone to write code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var compareTo = function() {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            otherModelValue: "=compareTo"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$validators.compareTo = function(modelValue) {
                return modelValue == scope.otherModelValue;
            };

            scope.$watch("otherModelValue", function() {
                ngModel.$validate();
            });
        }
    };
};

module.directive("compareTo", compareTo);


<input type="password" name="confirmPassword" 
        ng-model="registration.user.confirmPassword"
        required 
        compare-to="registration.user.password" />

<div ng-messages="registrationForm.confirmPassword.$error"
      ng-messages-include="messages.html"></div>
```

Have a look [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/10/13/confirm-password-validation-in-angularjs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that from controller. Compare both input boxes for values using their respective id's and pass the result to the scope.

Comment: Give id for both inputs. These inputboxes are then avialble from the controller. ($('#password').val()!=$('#confirmpassword').val()){ write the code here to pass it the scope object. $scope.pwderror=true}